# TinyMce in .Net Core App - Popup Closes after upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a .net core 2.1 website and I'm trying to integrate Tinymce 4 and the file upload process.  I have the file upload working using and API controller.  The image is put in the correct folder.  The problem is that once the upload is complete the popup closes almost immediately.  I did manage to get a screen shot of the popup after the image prior to it closing. The info is correct.

[image]

Here is my TinyMce init.js file:

```
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea.tinymce",
plugins: 'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview visualblocks',
toolbar: "link | image",
visualblocks_default_state: true,
images_upload_url: '/api/UploadService',
automatic_uploads: false,
images_reuse_filename: true,
images_upload_base_path: '/CMS/Content/UploadService/'
});
```

Here is my API controller:

```
    [Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UploadServiceController : Controller
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    public UploadServiceController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    // GET: api/test
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    //[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public JsonResult UploadFile()
    {
        string fileName = "";
        string folderName = "CMS/Content/UploadService/";
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile file;
        try
        {
            file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string newPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, folderName);
            if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
            }
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, fileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                }
            }
            return Json(new { location = $"{fileName}" });
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return Json("Upload Failed: " + ex.Message);
            //return Json(@"HTTP / 1.1 500 Server Error + ex.Message");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm unsure what is causing the window to close immediately or what I need to add to stop that.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: please let me know ,is the popup closing before pressing ok button?

Comment: Yes... sorry... It closes prior to clicking the ok button.  I think the page is doing a refresh once the request for the image finishes.

Comment: but its working fine on my browser I am using chrome

Comment: i'm trying to get this to work inside a .Net Core Razor pages application.

Comment: Oddly it doesn't populate the file when it comes in through the `IFormFile file` parameter in the `Action`, but digging it out from the request worked...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out in the startup.cs file I had 'app.UseBrowserLink();'

Removing that stopped the page from reloading and I could click the Ok button and my image was inserted.